# Как сделать плавную прозрачность?

Tags: вёрстка

Нужно сделать прозрачным элемет, но так чтобы прозрачность увеличивалась снизу вверх. Прошу вас помочь с этим.

Comment: [здень это описано](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/314562/Полупрозрачный-градиент-поверх-картинки)

Answer (score 1):

Используйте свойство `transition`. Это свойство устанавливает эффект плавного перехода между двумя состояниями элемента.

Comment: Как это поможет для "снизу вверх"?

Comment: "увеличивалась снизу вверх" - я это понял как плавный переход из одного цвета в другой. а если снизу вверх, или слева направо то нужно использовать градиент

Comment: Ваша удивительная логика сделала моему мозгу немножко больно

Answer (score 0):

Обратите внимание на `linear-gradient(transparent, #000)`.

```css
#transp {
background: linear-gradient(transparent, #000);
height: 100vh;
width: 100vw;
}

#wrapper {
background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="transp"></div>
</div>
```