# как сделать подобное затемнение на картинке при помощи css?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, frontend

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]всем привет,учусь на фронтенд разработчика верстаю макет для будущего портфолио.столкнулся с одной проблемой,не понимаю как затемнить контент как на картинке,не могу припомнить такого css свойства которое бы подходило.если поможете,буду очень благодарен

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Полупрозрачный градиент поверх картинки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/314562/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%85-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%b8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну самый простой способ, это использовать картинку с прозрачностью, оно будет работать везде, но чуть больше весить (потому что PNG).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Либо же использовать [`mask`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask) и градиент:

```css
body {background-color: #ccc;}

img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.mask-gradient {
  -webkit-mask: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(75%, #fff), color-stop(97.5%, transparent));
  -webkit-mask: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fff 75%, transparent 97.5%);
          mask: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(75%, #fff), color-stop(97.5%, transparent));
          mask: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff 75%, transparent 97.5%);
}
```

```html
<img class="mask-gradient" src="https://i.imgur.com/F5kM2mi.jpg" width="400">
```

Comment: С `mask` у вас какая-то ошибка.

Comment: @OliverPatterson, подробнее можно?

Comment: У меня показывает DevTools, что свойство "инвалид". У меня 111 хром.

Comment: @OliverPatterson, спасибо что заметили, да, для хрома [mask](https://caniuse.com/?search=mask) используется с префиксом `-webkit-`. Привычка работать с автопрефиксером, из-за чего забыл уже о префиксах)

Comment: почти работает,но показывает голубо цвет вместо зеленого(

Comment: Какого голубого? Какого зелёного? Вы прям просто скопировали мой ответ или как? Если да, то поиграйтесь с параметрами.

Answer (score 1):

Можно что-то такое сделать..

```css
.cont {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background: #4CB8B5;
}
.mask-gradient {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  border: green solid 1px;
}
.cont:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, #4CB8B5 11%, transparent 35%);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class='cont'>
  <img class="mask-gradient" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/c350c.png" width="400">
</div>
```